# How to solve this problem in O(logn) time complexity

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures

Problem Statement: Given a sorted array of integers, find the non-repeated integer from the given array. There will be only 1 non-repeated integer in the array and the other integer range will be 2.

Input : [1,1,2,2,4,5,5]
Output: 4

Input : [10,10,12,12,15,15,16,18,18]
Output: 16

Can anybody help me to solve this problem with O(log N) time complexity?

Note: N is the length of the array

Comment: I think there should be one more constraint. Maybe regarding the relationship between the number of elements and their range.

Comment: @LiorKogan has updated the statement I had missed the constraint.

Comment: You didn't state what N was. Please state it in the question. I am going to assume N is the length of the array, although that is only a guess. In that case, you can't possibly solve this in O(log N). That's not enough time to examine every element in the array - the only way this could work is if you could locate the element without examining every element. But the fact that the array is sorted doesn't really help finding the non-repeating element. What makes you think there is a solution in O(log N) ?

Comment: @Stef Because all the other numbers occur exactly twice, you can do a binary search for the single value, which is `O(logn)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**

It has been pointed out that the original code takes slices of the array, and  if this is done via a copy, it makes the complexity `O(n)`. So here are versions of the code that use pointers into the array instead:

Java:

```
public static int singleton(int[] arr, int lo, int hi) {
    if (hi == lo) return arr[hi];
    int m = (hi + lo) / 2;        
    if (m % 2 == 1) {
        if (arr[m] == arr[m-1]) return singleton(arr, m+1, hi);
        if (arr[m] != arr[m+1]) return arr[m];
        return singleton(arr, lo, m-1);
    }
    else {
        if (arr[m] == arr[m+1]) return singleton(arr, m+2, hi);
        if (arr[m] != arr[m-1]) return arr[m];
        return singleton(arr, lo, m);
    }
}      
    
public static void main(String args[])
{
    System.out.println(singleton(new int[]{ 1,1,2,2,4,5,5 }, 0, 6));
    System.out.println(singleton(new int[]{ 10,10,12,12,15,15,16,18,18 }, 0, 8));
    System.out.println(singleton(new int[]{1,2,2,5,5,6,6,7,7}, 0, 8));
    System.out.println(singleton(new int[]{1,1,2,5,5,6,6,7,7}, 0, 8));
    System.out.println(singleton(new int[]{10,10,12,12,15,15,16,16,18}, 0, 8));
}
```

Python:

```
def singleton(arr, lo, hi):
    if (hi == lo):
        return arr[hi]
    m = (hi + lo) // 2
    if (m % 2 == 1):
        if (arr[m] == arr[m-1]):
            return singleton(arr, m+1, hi)
        if (arr[m] != arr[m+1]):
            return arr[m]
        return singleton(arr, lo, m-1);
    else:
        if (arr[m] == arr[m+1]):
            return singleton(arr, m+2, hi)
        if (arr[m] != arr[m-1]):
            return arr[m]
        return singleton(arr, lo, m);
```

**Original Answer**

Because you know that all the other integers in the array occur exactly twice, you can do a binary search to find the value which only occurs once. You need to look for the mid-point of the array and work out whether the singleton occurs before, after, or is that number. If it is before or after, continue searching, but only that part (at most half) of the array. This is `O(logn)`. In python (Note: when I originally answered the question it was not tagged with `java` - I subsequently added a java solution below) you could implement this as:

```
def singleton(arr):
    m = len(arr) // 2
    if (m == 0):
        return arr[0]
    if m % 2 == 1:
        if arr[m] == arr[m-1]:
            return singleton(arr[m+1:])
        if arr[m] != arr[m+1]:
            return arr[m]
        return singleton(arr[:m])
    else:
        if arr[m] == arr[m+1]:
            return singleton(arr[m+2:])
        if arr[m] != arr[m-1]:
            return arr[m]
        return singleton(arr[:m+1])
```

Sample usage:

```
print(singleton([1,1,2,2,4,5,5]))
print(singleton([10,10,12,12,15,15,16,18,18]))
print(singleton([1,2,2,5,5,6,6,7,7]))
print(singleton([1,1,2,5,5,6,6,7,7]))
print(singleton([10,10,12,12,15,15,16,16,18]))
```

Output:

```
4
16
1
2
18
```

I'm not a java expert, so this may not be the most effective way of doing this, but it does work:

```
public static int singleton(int[] arr) {
    int m = arr.length / 2;
    if (m == 0) return arr[0];
    if (m % 2 == 1) {
        if (arr[m] == arr[m-1]) return singleton(Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, m+1, arr.length));
        if (arr[m] != arr[m+1]) return arr[m];
        return singleton(Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 0, m));
    }
    else {
        if (arr[m] == arr[m+1]) return singleton(Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, m+2, arr.length));
        if (arr[m] != arr[m-1]) return arr[m];
        return singleton(Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 0, m+1));
    }
}      
    
public static void main(String args[])
{
    System.out.println(singleton(new int[]{ 1,1,2,2,4,5,5 }));
    System.out.println(singleton(new int[]{ 10,10,12,12,15,15,16,18,18 }));
    System.out.println(singleton(new int[]{1,2,2,5,5,6,6,7,7}));
    System.out.println(singleton(new int[]{1,1,2,5,5,6,6,7,7}));
    System.out.println(singleton(new int[]{10,10,12,12,15,15,16,16,18}));
}
```

Comment: can you help with the java solution

Comment: @dev_mg99 see my edit. The code is functional if not the most efficient.

Comment: thanks for the solution I was a bit confused in this "arr[m+1:]" so I asked for java solution.

Comment: @dev_mg99 no worries - you hadn't tagged the question when I first answered so I just went with the language in which subarrays are easier to write. I hope the java code makes it obvious what `arr[m+1:]` means (the subarray of `arr` from index `m+1` to the end)

Comment: thanks for a really great solution. but there might bit problem in the time complexity. In every function call, you are creating a sub-array (Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, m+1, arr. length)) and it takes O(N) N means the subarray of arr from index m+1 to the end.i don't think so this will works for O(Log n) TC

Comment: @dev_mg99 sorry - wrote that late at night and wasn't thinking about copying. I've added new versions of the code which use array indexes instead of slices of the array. This should truly be O(logn)

Comment: @dev_mg99 no worries - I'm glad it worked well for you.